gitlab-runner: Failed to cleanup volumes / Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock
I recently switched one of my testing stages of the gitlab-ci to docker executor. This is not "docker-in-docker" - I am not building images here. The docker image I use is a python application which does the testing.
Sometimes, one of the jobs fail with messages:
ERROR: Failed to cleanup volumes
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:645:120s)

I am using GIT_STRATEGY=none so the gitlab-runner uses "temporary volumes" based on this gitlab issue.
I allow for up to 30 concurrent jobs currently.
I went digging in /var/log/messages and found the following messages:
Apr 17 00:42:55 dbserver1 gitlab-runner: #033[31;1mERROR: Failed to cleanup volumes                  #033[0;m  #033[31;1merror#033[0;m=remove temporary volumes: Error response from daemon: remove runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-6-5e08b0d75056ac23-cache-c33bcaa1fd2c77edfc3893b41966cea8: volume is in use - [fdb31dbe3ab4ecd7968f9a6de7063385125300cf1ecc70510d35e48f4f3dfdce] (manager.go:246:0s) #033[31;1mjob#033[0;m=678913 #033[31;1mproject#033[0;m=24 #033[31;1mrunner#033[0;m=LyN8NZySG
Apr 17 00:42:55 dbserver1 gitlab-runner: #033[31;1mERROR: Job failed (system failure): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:645:120s)#033[0;m  #033[31;1mduration_s#033[0;m=274.799512162 #033[31;1mjob#033[0;m=678913 #033[31;1mproject#033[0;m=24 #033[31;1mrunner#033[0;m=LyN8NZySG

I've noticed a lot of these "temporary" volumes are still around - notice how the one causing the error is the only one with different naming scheme:
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-0-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-1-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-2-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-3-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-4-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-5-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-6-5e08b0d75056ac23-cache-c33bcaa1fd2c77edfc3893b41966cea8
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-6-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-7-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-8-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-9-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-10-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-11-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-12-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-13-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-14-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-15-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-16-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-17-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-18-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-19-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-20-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-21-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-21-cache-c33bcaa1fd2c77edfc3893b41966cea8
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-24-concurrent-22-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-0-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-1-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-2-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-3-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-4-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-5-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-6-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-7-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-8-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-9-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-10-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-11-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-12-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-13-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-14-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-15-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-35-concurrent-16-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-0-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-1-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-2-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-3-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-4-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-5-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-6-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-7-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-8-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-9-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-10-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-11-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-12-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-13-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-14-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-15-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-140-concurrent-16-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-256-concurrent-0-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-256-concurrent-1-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-256-concurrent-2-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-256-concurrent-3-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-256-concurrent-4-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-256-concurrent-5-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-256-concurrent-6-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-256-concurrent-7-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-256-concurrent-8-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-256-concurrent-9-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-256-concurrent-10-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70
local     runner-lyn8nzysg-project-256-concurrent-11-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70

Once I restart the job, it proceeds correctly without errors.
What could be causing this? Any suggestions on what I should check, configure, etc.?
